# Failed to resolve play-service-places-placereport

Tags: android, google-play-services

After adding `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1` this dependencies i am getting failed to resolve `play-service-places-placereport` issue. And even if i add `com.google.android.gms:play-service-places-placereport:15.0.1` also it is not resolve please help on this

Comment: paste your gradle build(app)

Comment: ext {
    supportLibVersion = '26.1.0'
    firebase = '16.0.1'
    firebaseMessage = '17.0.0'
    firebaseAuth = '16.0.1'
    googlePlay = "15.0.1"
    googlePlaces = "15.0.1"
    placeReport = "15.0.1"
    firebaseCore = "16.0.0"
    firebaseConfig = "16.0.0"
    firebaseDatabase = "16.0.1"
}

Comment: implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${googlePlay}"
    //implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${googlePlay}"
    //implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-placereport:${googlePlay}"
    /*implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${googlePlay}"

Comment: not hear, edit your question and paste there with full gradle build(app) code

Comment: This is my fulll gradle file https://justpaste.it/4q9go , If i comment implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1" this dependency and re enable location dependency i am getting failed to resolve play-service-places-placereport error

Comment: @MohammadAli What is the issue with my gradle

Comment: 1st of all tell me which library u can need for work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171968/discussion-between-honeyl-and-mohammad-ali).

Comment: Now it's work fine or not ?

Comment: It is Working Fine

Comment: okay enjoy :)..